# Change cy percentage based on Legend height

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have the following code:

```
<PieChart width={w} height={h} style={{fontSize:font}}>
    <Pie label={false} labelLine={false} legendType="circle" data={this.getEthnicityValues()} dataKey="total" paddingAngle={1} minAngle={1}
            nameKey="Ethnicity" cx="50%" cy="30%" outerRadius={rad}>
        {
            this.getEthnicityValues().map((entry, index) => (
                <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={this.colors[index]}/>
            ))
        }
    </Pie>
    <Tooltip/>
    <Legend/>
</PieChart>)
```

I am trying to change the cy position of the chart based on the height or number of lines the legend takes up. Currently the chart overlaps with the legend and I need to to draw based on a ratio, not a hard percentage number.

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as a good use for classic JS + CSS.

1. Add `id="theChart"` to the `Pie` component.
2. Add `id="theLegend"` to the `Legend` component.
3. Add the following CSS project (using whatever is best for your stack): `#theLegend { visibility: hidden }` to hide the chart on initial render.
4. Then, from `componentDidMount` (and `componentDidUpdate` if necessary) call a positioning function.

Eg.:

```
figureChartPosition() {
  const legHeight = gotComputedStyle(document.getElementById('theLegend')).height;
  const chart = document.getElementById('theChart');
  const yPos = ... do some calculation ...
  chart.style.top = yPos;
  chart.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

The above is a guideline. I don't how the positioning is working currently so it may make sense to manipulate something other than `top`. I'd use browser dev tools to see how it's currently being set and manipulate the same value in the same way to get the positioning you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ResponsiveContainer fixed my problem. I thought initially it wouldn't because I didn't know it would keep thew legend size and fill in the rest of the pie chart. Exactly what I needed. I still wished I had a way to keep track of these separate so I could make more room for the charts if needed.